# navigate to particular site home page when click XE button in launch pad

Tags: sxa, multisite

we are using sitecore 9 update 2 and SXA 1.7.1 and we have 2 sites called site1(english) and site2(Korean). both sites created separately in SXA.

when click Experience Editor button in launch pad always navigate to site1's home page as we have configure this into Core database.

now issue is that when korean user(associated with Korean role) login, He is also navigating to site1's home page.

is there any way to navigate to particular site's home page based on user's role.

Thanks.

Comment: but it will create duplicate buttons for Administrator. how to avoid that.

Comment: There isn't a way to do that with Sitecore security. What would you want to happen for Administrators?

Comment: for administrator, it should always navigate to site1's home page.

Comment: I would recommend following the solution in the other question and simply naming the Korean homepage EE button differently (e.g. `Experience Editor (Korea)`) so it's clear which is which.